# Adding GeometryCollections with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I've build a form in Angular to add GeoJSON features to MongoDB using Mongoose. The features include several properties and a GeometryCollection with a point and a lineString.

Here comes the trouble: I was able to create features with just a single point in my geometry but I'm unable to create features with a geometry collection that uses a lineString. I get either:

```
16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?
```

or:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to number failed for value "0,0,1,1" at path "coordinates"]
  message: 'Cast to number failed for value "0,0,1,1" at path "coordinates"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'number',
  value: [[0,0],[1,1]],
  path: 'coordinates' }'
```

I do realize it says type: 'number' while my schema is set to an array of arrays:

```
var featureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  'type': {
    type: String,
    default: "Feature"
  },
  geometry: {
    'type': {
      type: String,
      default: 'GeometryCollection',
    }, geometries: [{
      'type': {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point'
      },
      coordinates:  [Number]
    }, {
      'type': {
        type: String,
        default: 'LineString'
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Array],
        default: [[0,0], [1,1]]
      }
    }]
  },
  properties: {
    title: String
  }
});
```

So my first question is: does anyone know how to properly add features using GeometryCollections with Mongoose?

My second question is how to add an array of arrays when using forms? When I use a text input now I get my array of arrays delivered as a string. I was able to convert the point coordinates using:

```
var array = req.body.feature.geometry.geometries.coordinates.split(',');
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = +array[i];
}
```

Is there a way to convert a string (ie "[ [0,0], [1,1] ]") to an array of arrays to create the lineString coordinates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i haven't got an answer to your question but the first thing i'm spotting is that you're setting the coordinates for type point in your schema to number type. coordinates are always an array, or an array of arrays. that's where your error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @iH8. The point/first part of the GeometryCollection does actually work, [Number] is an array of numbers and I was able to create features with it. It's the lineString/second part I'm having trouble with. Can anybody else help me?

Comment: I've found a predefined set of schemas and added an answer. I think if you use those or take those as an example and roll your own, it will work nicely

Comment: I'm basically already using those schemas in one schema. It seems more that the error has to do with Mongoose having a hard time to recognize array of arrays. Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to split this into multiple schemas, which is much easier to read, use and maintain. For example:

```
GeoJSON.FeatureCollection = {
    "type"  : {
        "type": String,
        "default": "FeatureCollection"
    },
    "features": [GeoJSON.Feature]
}

GeoJSON.Feature = {
    "id": {
        "type": "String"
    },
    "type": {
        "type": String,
        "default": "Feature"
    },
    "properties": {
        "type": "Object"
    },
    "geometry": GeoJSON.Geometry
}

GeoJSON.GeometryCollection = {
    "type": {
        "type": String,
        "default": "GeometryCollection"
    },
    "geometries": [GeoJSON.Geometry]
}

GeoJSON.Geometry = {
    "type": {
        "type": String,
        "enum": [
            "Point",
            "MultiPoint",
            "LineString",
            "MultiLineString",
            "Polygon",
            "MultiPolygon"
        ]
    },
    "coordinates": []
}
```

Taken from: https://github.com/RideAmigosCorp/mongoose-geojson-schema